# Custom GD Star Ratings Stars

Tags: plugins, theme-development, plugin-gd-star-rating

I have some custom stars that I would like to use for GD Star Ratings.. how do I load my custom star image?

Comment: _Google something for me_ or _Read the manual for me_ is not exactly a good question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin supports this feature by default. Searching for "gd star ratings custom images" finds lots of information including [this guide](http://www.gdstarrating.com/2009/01/21/installing-additional-sets/) on the official site. Apparently the [GD Stars User Guide](http://www.gdstarrating.com/downloads/user-guide/) contains full instructions on creating new image sets as well as some pre-built ones you can use.